# Strings and Palindromes Counting

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

Hoping to check my work!

1. How many length-5 strings have at least one each of the letters A,B,C. Meaning, it has to have at least one A, one B, and one C. I put down $3*3*3*2*1$. I thought so b/c you could have any for the first three, but if they were all the same, then you'd have to pick the other two, hence the $2 * 1$.
2. How many length-5 number-based palindromes are there? I believe there's $10^3$ because you can do whatever for the first three digits, and once that's decided you only have one choice for the other 2 digits.

Comment: For problem 1, is a length-5 string allowed to use any letters other than A, B, or C?  For problem 2, is the leftmost digit allowed to be $0$?  That is, is $01210$ considered a valid palindrome?  If so, then I agree with your answer for #2.  If not, then you still have some work to do on #2.

Comment: @user2661923 hi! thanks for your reply! for the first question, no, we can only use A,B, and C. For problem 2, I just checked, the leftmost cant be 0. Then I guess in that case its $9*10^2$?

Comment: Yes, just as Toby Mak's answer indicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For question $1$, you should subtract from the total number of permutations, which is just $3^5$. If there are only two letters, say $A$ and $B$, there are $2^5$ ways to permute them. Now there are $3$ choose $2 = 3$ ways to choose the two letters, so there are $3 \cdot 2^5$ ways. But the $3$ combinations $AAAAA, BBBBB$ and $CCCCC$ are counted twice, as if you choose $A, C$, $AAAAA$ and $CCCCC$ are both valid arrangements. Hence you have to subtract $3 \cdot 2^5$ by $3$, so the total number of ways is $3^5 - \left(3 \cdot 2^5 - 3\right) = 150$.

For question $2$, you are correct except that the leftmost digit cannot be $0$. Therefore, there are only $9 \cdot 10 \cdot 10 = 900$ ways.

Comment: I know. I am subtracting all the ways where $A, B$ and $C$ do not appear from the total.

Comment: I don't know yet. I suspect the answer must be divisible by ${5 \choose 2}$ or ${5 \choose 3} = 10$, so it is possible I am missing a case.

Comment: When you add up the combinations, it is more likely that you will overcount. For that reason, I do believe the answer is $144$, but that doesn't tell us anything about your solution.

Comment: hi! Whats the intuition behind grouping it like $2^5-2$ if $2^5$ is for the case that there's two letters and 2 is for the case that there's one?

Comment: To avoid double counting. If you choose $B$ and $C$, $BBBBB$ and $CCCCC$ are valid combinations, but if you choose $A$ and $B$, $AAAAA$, $BBBBB$ are valid combinations, and likewise for $A$ and $C$.

Comment: hmm also why dont we substract -6 instead of 3? Cuz none of those use 3 letters

Comment: also should the - be outside the paranthesis so when it distributes it's -3 and not +3?

Comment: No, the $3$ should be inside. If you subtract $6$, then you will not count $AAAAA$, $BBBBB$ and $CCCCC$ as invalid arrangements.

Answer (score 1):

My comment handles question 2, and is pending a response from the OP.

Problem 1 is complex.  I will assume that only the letters A,B,and C are allowed.  I am also going to assume that the string AAABC is construed to be different from (for example CBAAA).  That is, the order of the letters is important.

I will break up question 1 into cases.

**case 1** 
3 of one letter.  Assume AAA.
Then, the B has 5 slots and the C then has 4 slots.
Also, you have 3 choices for which letter is the triplet. 
$C_1 = 3 \times 5 \times 4 = 60.$

**case 2** 
distribution of 2-2-1. 
Assume that odd man out is $C$.
You have 5 choices for the $C$.
Once that is picked, the $AA$ can go in 
$\binom{4}{2}$ different configurations.
$C_2 = 3 \times 5 \times 6 = 90.$

Total is $C_1 + C_2 = 150.$

Comment: Hi! I sorta get it, but what do you mean B has 5 slots? Just the place it can go? Do we not need to consider A's slots? And the 3 in case 2 is the 3 choices for which letter is the odd man out?

Comment: @MelanieSanders In Case 1, under the assumption of the triplet AAA, I have to compute the # of ways that B and C can be placed, with the assumption that the AAA will take whatever 3 slots remain.  Initially with no slots taken, there are 5 choices of where to put the B.  Then, regardless of which slot is given to B, there will be 4 remaining slots to choose from re where to put the C.